# initializing values in Mars 4.5 getting an error

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

My homework is to initialize values in certain registers. We have to turn off Permit extended (pseudo) instructions and formats.

When i try to assemble the code i get this error message for line 7,8,9

Extended (pseudo) instruction or format not permitted.

Also is there a way to optimize the code? We startet Assembly language last week so im pretty new to it.

```
.text
addi $8, $0, 1
addi $9, $0, 11
addi $10, $0, 0x1000
addi $11, $0, -1
addi $12, $0, -0x8000
addi $13, $0, 0x8000
addi $14, $0, 0xffff0000
addi $15, $0, 0x7fffffff
addi $24, $0, 5322
addi $25, $0, 75
```

Answer (score 1):

`addi`instruction requires a 16 bits signed parameter. On 16 bits, you can code from -32768 (-0x8000) to +32767 (0x7fff).

Instruction 7 `addi $13, $0, 0x8000` is out of range (+32768).

And instructions 8 `addi $14, $0, 0xffff0000` and 9 `addi $15, $0, 0x7fffffff` even more.

Initializing a registers with an  argument with more than 16 significant bits requires in general two instructions. That is the purpose of macros instructions such as `li` that can load in two instructions a 32 integer or `la` that does the same with an address (label).

Basically, what must be done, to load 0x01234567 in $2, is first loading the high order bits with `lui` (load upper immediate), then or it with the lower part of the argument.

```
lui $2, 0x0123     # load the upper part and clears 16 LSBs
                   # content of $2 is 0x01230000
ori $2, $2, 0x4567 # ors with the 16 least significant bits
```

Note that `ori` (and `andi, xori`) consider their operand as logical and do not perform sign extension. Operand is just is zero extended.

So, you could replace ligne 7 by

```
ori $13, $0, 0x8000
```

to have a valid initialization in one instruction.

Similarly, instruction 8 immediate has all its 16 LSB cleared and initialization can be done in a unique lui

```
lui $14, 0xffff
```

For line 9, two instructions are required

```
lui $15, 0x7fff     
ori $15, $15, 0xffff
```

There in no way to really optimize the code. To initialize 10 different registers, you need at least 10 instructions.

Comment: Thank you. It was easy to understand. you said for line 8 it can be done like that lui $14, $0, 0xffff . when i assembled the code i got the error message line 8 column 2: "lui": Too many or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: lui $t1,100
Assemble: operation completed with errors. i changed it to lui  $14, 0xffff and it worked

Comment: I have another question why is 0xffffffff equal to -1?

Comment: Sorry lui just have an operand and it was an incorrect cut-paste. I fixed the code in the answer. Concerning 0xffffffff=-1, it is the way signed integers are coded on (almost) all the computers (2's complement), but it is diffcult to give an explanation in some words.  Most probably, you had some lectures on that. Or have a look at wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement And there are probably plenty of answers on SO

Comment: i have another problem i posted it as an answer